# Предупреждение IDE в самодельном декораторе

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, декоратор

Есть класс *QtPy5*, в нём есть методы. Перед тем как их выполнить нужно проверить загружен ли пользователь.

Декоратор вида:

```
def is_active_user(func):
    """декоратор для определения активен ли юзер"""
    def wrapper(self):
        if not self.USER_active:
            return self.statusbar.showMessage('Загрузи хоть одного пользователя', 2000)
        else:
            return func(self)
    return wrapper
```

*PyCharm* выдаёт предупреждение над **`func(self)`**:

> This inspection highlights attempts to call objects which are not callable, like, for example, tuples.

Когда декорирую метод:

**`@is_active_user`** - подсвечивается:

> This inspection reports discrepancies between declared parameters and actual arguments, as well as incorrect arguments (e.g. duplicate named arguments) and incorrect argument order. Decorators are analyzed, too.

и вроде всё работает, но что-то я не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import threading

import functools                                                 # +++

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


def is_active_user(func):
    """декоратор для определения активен ли юзер"""

    print(f'\nfunc   : name={func.__name__}, \n\t module={func.__module__}, \n\t doc={func.__doc__}, \n\t dict={func.__dict__}')

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self):
        if not self.USER_active:
            return print('Загрузи хоть одного пользователя', 2000)
        else:
            print('++++++++++')
            return func(self)

    print(f'\nwrapper: name={wrapper.__name__}, \n\t module={wrapper.__module__}, \n\t doc={wrapper.__doc__}, \n\t dict={wrapper.__dict__}')
    return wrapper


class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.USER_active = True                   # True or False

    @is_active_user
    def some_function(self):
        print(f'some_function is running on thread -> {threading.current_thread().name}')


class Main(QObject):   
    signal_for_function = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        print(f'\nThe main thread is -> {threading.current_thread().name}')

        self.thread = QThread(self)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.start()

        self.signal_for_function.connect(self.worker.some_function)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
m = Main()
m.signal_for_function.emit()

QThread.msleep(1000)
m.thread.quit()
m.thread.wait()
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, да нужно было просто декоратор вынести из класса, и тогда IDE перестало выдавать предупреждения.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте подсказку типа [typing.Callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable):

```
from typing import Callable

def is_active_user(func: Callable):
    ...
```